# Need Kafka 3 migration guide

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

I'm trying to migrate Kafka from 2.4.0 to 3.4.0.  There are some breaking changes, such as:

- `kafka.server.NotRunning` is gone.
- `kafka.server.KafkaConfig.port()` is gone.

Could someone please point me to the upgrade guide so I know how to handle these changes?

I scanned https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-3-0-major-improvements-and-new-features/ and didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: Your code should not be using either class directly... What are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: I'm new to the project so can't say for sure but there's a class in the tests that uses those classes.

Comment: What kinds of tests? Are you using 3rd party libraries like TestContainers, Spring EmbeddedKafka, Junit-Kafka, etc? If not, you may want to migrate to those, and see if they offer Kafka 3.x support